# Smart Contract's ABI has uint256, but I get error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'BigNumber'

Tags: ethers.js, react, wagmi

This is the first time I work with web3 api, so I am totally lost.
I use wagmi hook with react, trying to call a function from smart contract:

```
const id = 1;
const index = 1;

 const { data, error, isError, isLoading } = useContractRead({
    address: "0xADDRESS",
    abi: [(...){
        inputs: [
          { internalType: "uint256", name: "id", type: "uint256" },
          { internalType: "uint256", name: "index", type: "uint256" },
        ],
        name: "isClaimed",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "bool", name: "", type: "bool" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
      },(...)],
    functionName: "isClaimed",
    args: [id, index],
  });
```

and I get the IDE error: "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'BigNumber'"

if I then

```
const id = BigNumber.from(1);
```

then I get error from the contract:

> Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="isClaimed(uint256,uint256)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0) at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1) at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1) at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.ts:427:1) at index.ts:400:1 at Generator.next () at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)

I watched several tutorials and read articles about it but still have no idea what is the problem. Wagmi documentation doesn't tell me anything about it. ChatGPT nor Bing Chat are not helpful. Can anyone help?

------------ Edit: Additional Info ----------------

I have this in my App.txs:

```
const chains = [arbitrum, mainnet, polygon];
const projectId = "SOME_ID_OF_WALLETCONNECT_PROJECT_I_CREATED";

const { provider } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })]);
const wagmiClient = createClient({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: w3mConnectors({ projectId, version: 1, chains }),
  provider,
});
```

Contract developer said that chain is Mumbai testing for polygon. I guess I am not connected to the correct chain then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error you pasted seems a bit unrelated to the description. The error shows that you are calling  method `isClaimed(uint256,uint256)`
with `data=0x`. Perhaps you are making a call somewhere to that method without providing input arguments?

It is difficult to say without seeing the rest of the code.

-----------------------------  EDIT --------------------------------

The exception provides you this link:
https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION

This type of exception happens if you try to access a method that doesn't exist for a specific address. A very common case is that you try to access "the right method and the right address" but in the wrong network. Make sure you are only trying to call that contract method in the chain where it is deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated the question. This is the first time I work with web3 functions and I am lost, confused with terminology

Comment: I solved the issue yesterday when the contract dev pointed out I need to use polygonMumbai. 
So I guess your answer is the same. Thanks

Comment: Glad it was solved!